# TKinter scales and GUI update

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter to create a GUI, that contains scales buttons, etc. 
Now, I have this collection of scales. And I know that scales can be updated with `scale.set()`
Now, I have a list of the form `[[1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1],[3,3,3,3,3]]` for example.

I want to go through each element of the list (eg [1,2,3,4,5]) and update the scales with the values of this element (which is also a list)

So I do

```
def runMotion():
    #r=3
    for n in range(len(list)):
        print(list[n])
        for count in range(5):
            print(list[n][count])
            motorList[count].scale.set(list[n][count])
            #motorList[count].moveTo(list[n][count])
        time.sleep(5)
```

Here motorList is an array of classes that each has a scale, therefore `motorList[count].scale`

The thing is that the GUI (the scales) are not updated, except the last one (in our case [3,3,3,3,3]
The GUI gets freezed while executing and only the last "motion" is reflected in the scale values.

I am a beginner in python, specially doing GUIs and I would appreciate advice here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you're using a "for" loop which blocks the TK event loop. This means that things are calculated by your program, but the GUI does not update. Try the following:

```
list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1],[3,3,3,3,3]]

def runMotion(count):
    if len(list) == count:
        return
    print(list[count])
    for index,n in enumerate(list[count]):
        print(index,n)
        motorList[index].set(n)
        #motorList[count].moveTo(list[n][count])
    root.after(5000, lambda c=count+1: runMotion(c))

root = Tk()
motorList = []
for i in range(1,6):
    s = Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
    s.grid(row=i-1)
    motorList.append(s)
runMotion(0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I will read about your solution to understand it. Just one question: Is runMotion being called recursively?

Comment: I ask this because in the program I am writing, in a next version I am going to be running this indefinitely and I don't want to freeze the GUI or run out of resources

Comment: Technically, runMotion is being scheduled on the event stack. The event loop (mainloop) checks the event stack frequently, and if an event is scheduled to run, it runs it. That is what the root.after(5000...) command is doing -- placing an event each time runMotion is finishing. This has the effect of doing the GUI updates without blocking user input within the GUI, and allows the GUI to visually update prior to the next runMotion event.